# Make a JtextPane looks like eBook

Tags: java, swing, paging, jtextpane

I have a text editor with Netbeans where i load a text to a JtextPane. If text is too big u can read it with the help of an horizontal scroll.Is there any way to split the text into pages of 24 lines for example so that every page is visible without scrolling and use a next page button for changing page (like eBooks do)?

Comment: yes that possible, notice --> wrote code by your hands, don't use JComponents from built-in palette

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use a JTextArea to do this because you can easily specify the number of lines to display each time you scroll to a new page.

The basic solution is to add a text area to a scroll pane than then hide the scrollbars. You can then use the defaults Actions of the vertical scrollbar to do the scrolling for you. The code below uses code from the [Action Map Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/action-map-action/) blog entry to easily create an Action that you can add to a JButton:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextAreaScroll extends JPanel
{
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public TextAreaScroll()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 80);
        textArea.setEditable( false );

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER );
        add(scrollPane);

        JButton load = new JButton("Load TextAreaScroll.java");
        load.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader( "TextAreaScroll.java" );
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    textArea.read( br, null );
                    br.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e2) { System.out.println(e2); }
            }
        });
        add(load, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //  Add buttons to do the scrolling

        JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();

        Action nextPage = new ActionMapAction("Next Page", vertical, "positiveBlockIncrement");
        nextPage.putValue(AbstractAction.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_N);
        JButton nextButton = new JButton(nextPage);

        Action previousPage = new ActionMapAction("Previous Page", vertical, "negativeBlockIncrement");
        previousPage.putValue(AbstractAction.MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_N);
        JButton previousButton = new JButton(previousPage);

        JPanel south = new JPanel();
        add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        south.add( previousButton );
        south.add( nextButton );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextAreaScroll());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When i display the page i choose i want to be an a Jtextpane to do some other things. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, but I'll get back to you in 9 days since the question is not that important to you.

Comment: I mean i want all the pages displayed in the Jtextpane. Is there a way to have a string Paging with Paging[1] takes the first page and so on..